# EdiFabric Could not load file or assembly. A strongly-named assembly is required

Tags: edi, edifabric

I am building an Edi translation and import program using EdiFabric. I love the simplicity of EdiFabric, but my unit tests are blowing up with an error message that says:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EdiFabric.Framework, Version=6.7.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80131044).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the the EdiFabric mailing list?

Comment: Can you check the references for any marked with a yellow exclamation ? The only strongly typed assemblies referenced are the .NET framework ones. Do you have .NET 4.5 installed as a minimum ?

Comment: There are no yellow exclamation points on any of the references.  The error message has to do with strongly-named assemblies, not strongly typed. 

It's not uncommon for 3rd party assemblies to be unsigned, but when I forked the repository and checked the project properties, I did notice that a signing certificate was listed, so I was a bit confused as to why they were not signed in the nuGet package.
 
I use strong named signing on our projects and the InternalsVisibleTo attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs file for our unit tests, but that means all the DLLs need to be signed.

Comment: There is no mailing list. All technical questions regarding ediFabric should be posted to StackOverflow under the edi tag as we advised on edifabric.com

Comment: No dll\project should be strongly named, it's probably a left over or made it into the release by mistake. Could you please upgrade to version 6.7.9 as that's the official latest.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that none of your DLLs are strongly named.  That's the problem. My DLLs are all strongly named so dependent DLLs, like your framework won't load unless they are strongly named.  I've upgraded to 6.7.9.  You are correct, they are not strongly named.  Thus the problem.

Comment: Got it now, I thought you meant that the Framework assembly was strongly named but the Unit Test wasn't and that was the problem. You can use the release from GitHub and sign them with your own key.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to strong name sign the DLL on my own. Following the information found here: [Signing unsigned assemblies in nuGetPackages](http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2013/04/30/Signing-unsigned-assemblies-in-NuGet-packages)

Comment: I'm glad that you resolved it. The question then was "How to sign unsigned assemblies in NuGet packages?" rather than anything specific to ediFabric.

Comment: No more self signing of DLLs!  Way to go!  That's very helpful.